# Match two files by column line by line - no key

Tags: arrays, awk

I have two large files of 80,000 plus records that are identical in length. I need to compare the two files line by line by the first 8 characters of the file. Line one of file one is to be compared to line one of file two. Line two of file one is to be compared to line two of file two.

Sample file1

```
01234567blah blah1
11234567blah blah2
21234567blah blah3
31234567blah blah4
```

Sample file2

```
31234567blah nomatch
11234567matchme2
21234567matchme3
31234567matchme4
```

Lines 2 - 4 should match but line 1 should not. My script matches line 1 to line 4 but should be compared to just line 1.

```
awk '                                                        
FNR==NR {                                                  
a[substr($0,1,8)]=1;next                                       
        }                                                              
{if (a[substr($0,1,8)])print $0; else print "Not Found", $0;} 
'  $inputfile1  $inputfile2     >  $outputfile1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For line by line compare you need to use `FNR` variable as key. Try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=substr($1,1,8);next}{print (a[FNR]==substr($1,1,8)?$0:"Not Found")}' file1 file2
Not Found
11234567matchme2
21234567matchme3
31234567matchme4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  while(1){
    f=getline<"file1";
    if(f!=1)exit;
    a=substr($0,1,8);
    f=getline<"file2";
    if(f!=1)exit;
    b=substr($0,1,8);
    print a==b?$0:"Not Found"FS$0}}'
```

Reads one line from `file1` if successful stores the substring in `a` then one line from `file2` if successful stores the substring in `b`, then checks whether `a` and `b` are equal or not and prints the output.

Output:

```
Not Found 31234567blah nomatch
11234567matchme2
21234567matchme3
31234567matchme4
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a single char not in either file you could use as a delimiter, like `:` in your example, and a `paste`/`awk` combo like:

```
paste -d: data data2 | awk -F: '{prefix=substr($1,1,8)!=substr($2,1,8) ? "Not Found"OFS : ""; print prefix $2}'
```

- paste joins the corresponding lines from each file into one line, with a `:` separator
- awk uses the `:` delimiter
- awk tests for a match on the first 8 chars of each field and creates `prefix`
- awk prints out every line with a `prefix` that's "Not Found" (+`OFS`) when they don't match.